# How to get product cost in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

We can use {{ product.price | money }} to get the price, is there a way can get the cost? {{ product.cost | money }} doesn't work...

Comment: cost price of a variant is buried in the inventory item setup in Shopify. It is not readily available for rendering in a theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible.

Perhaps using a metafield you could subtract against the price of the product.

And if you must send it to the cart you can pass that value as an attribute of the product.